# borg failed to create/acquire the lock.exclusive

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, backup

When running a backup script through a scheduled Jenkins job on many servers, I receive the following error on `borg create` command:

```
Failed to create/acquire the lock /path/to/repo/lock.exclusive (timeout).
terminating with error status, rc 2
```

OS : Ubuntu 18.04 Bionic and Ubuntu 20.04 Focal
Borg version: 1.1.15
PS: I had tried some solution like `borg break-lock`, and upgrade the borg version to the latest 1.1.17 and same problem

**Update:**

Fixed adding `--max-lock-wait 3600` to borg create command to increase lock-wait timeout by default it is 2 seconds, Thanks to **ThomasWaldmann** from BorgBackup community.
https://github.com/borgbackup/borg/issues/6047#issuecomment-967092381

Answer (score 7):

I had the same problem in Borg 1.20. [My search](https://www.google.com/search?q=borg%20%22Failed%20to%20create%2Facquire%20the%20lock%22) led to a few suggestions, including:

- Delete `<BackupDir>/lock.roster` (see [ITGrenade](https://itgrenade.wordpress.com/2020/09/26/borg-backup-error-failed-to-create-acquire-the-lock/))
- If it doesn't work to make sure there are no other backups running, and then use `borg break-lock` as described in [the manual](https://borgbackup.readthedocs.io/en/latest/internals/data-structures.html#lock-files), check `ps aux` or just restart to ensure borg is not still running (see [SolvedTips](https://www.solved.tips/failed-create-acquire-lock/))

I had success with a variation on the latter: unmount the Borg drive, delete the mount point, make sure nothing else is running that might lock the drive, and then recreate the mount point and restart the Borg process.